# Postgresql regex replace numbers to asterisks

Tags: regex, postgresql

I use Postgresql and need to replace numbers to asterisk at database layer. Howerver I'm new to learn regex and seems to be hard to do this with my current knowledge.

I will have in my database 16 numbers varchar and I need to replace middle numbers with asterisk.

Example.
123467812345678 -> 12**********5678

Could someone tell me how regex for this should look like in postgresql ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `(?<=..).(?=....)`

Comment: see also https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Wiktor Stribiżew:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('123467812345678', '(?<=..).(?=....)', '*','g');
```

Comment: Thanks Wiktor and Frank. It solves my problem